# Upgrading Aurora Postgres Engine Version via Cloudformation

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I am looking to upgrade from PostgreSQL to Aurora PostgreSQL and running into an issue when trying to test an upgrade in my CFT I specify the EngineVersion for my DB Cluster as 9.6.11 but I can’t update that to 9.6.12 as it requires a replacement of the cluster stack. If i deploy my stack out without the EngineVersion for the Cluster then it defaults to 9.6.9 which is below the version I want PostgreSQL at. I was able to upgrade the Cluster from 9.6.11 to 9.6.12 via the CLI but when i updated the EngineVersion in the CFT for the cluster to 9.6.12 it still wanted to create a new Cluster Stack even though the version was changed to 9.6.12 via the CLI. Is there a good way to get around this using CloudFormation?

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I'm running into the same problem while trying to upgrade from Aurora Postgres 9.6.11 to 10.11. CloudFormation wants to replace the cluster which wipes out the database. I think what we need to do is the following:

1. Use Console or CLI to update the Engine version
2. Snapshot the database
3. Delete the CloudFormation stack
4. Rebuild the CloudFormation stack restoring from the Snapshot taken in step 2

This seems a little wonky to me, but I'm not sure how else to update the engine version and also get CloudFormation in sync with the resources. Using the Console or CLI to update the engine version will cause drift in the template, so the only recourse is to delete the stack and recreate it.